# How to save a symbol or graphic style in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I designed a link button in Illustrator, much like the *ask question* button here.

Since I am new to all this, I have difficulties creating just the perfect shape every time, so **I want to save that button as a symbol or graphic style so that the next time I can just click on it and change the text length.**

How do I save as a symbol or graphic style?

Answer (score 1):

First, you open the panel you want to use -

<kbd>Window</kbd>-><kbd>Graphic Styles</kbd>

and/or

<kbd>Window</kbd>-><kbd>Symbols</kbd>

Next, you select the shape which style you want to save or convert to symbol and drag it to the appropriate panel.

Finally, you save the libraries by pressing small drop-down menu menu -

[image]

and/or

[image]

(the question asked in part [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/29558/how-to-create-a-global-style-like-drop-shadow))