# How do I change a color from a swatch library and actually change all the objects that have that color applied in the document?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, swatches

Is there a way to create a swatch library, apply different colors from that swatches library to a lot of objects (e.g. a red swatch to 30 objects, a lime swatch to 170 objects, etc.) and after, If I want to change the red to dark red without selecting layers/groups, just by changing the colors directly from the swatches window?

---

**Example:**

I apply different colors from a custom swatch library to a lot of objects. I should be able to edit the Cyan (selected) swatch to Black?

[image]

And after I change the Cyan color to black directly in the swatch window (?). This way I don't need to look for the

[image]

This is just a simple example, I have documents with more colors than this, I want a fast way to change the swatches colors for the whole document layers/objects without looking in the layers window for groups and objects and selecting them individually.

Comment: I've found the answer here (using Graphic Styles): https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/29561/108416

Answer (score 3):

- Create a new Swatch or select the Swatch you want to use
- Pressing <kbd>Cmd</kbd> in Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> in Win, click the color you want to replace
- Go to the **Swatches Options Menu** → **Merge Swatches**

[image: Colors]

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use Graphic Styles for this kind of in-document vidsual management and use swatch libraries for, well, global colour swatch bases.

Answer (score 0):

I often use the 'Select → Select Same → Stroke Color' (or fill, or whichever) then select the swatch you'd like to switch all selected objects to.