# Is there a way to use the eyedropper in the color picker in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a global swatch I'd like to change with another color using the eyedropper, without having to select all the elements and apply the new color manually.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Do you mean a way to apply a global color to elements *without* selecting them? I don't think it's possible.

Comment: Have you tried select > same and pick by color? (off the top of my head)

Comment: @Scott well, i can change a color without selection, if the color is global. but i cannot use the eyedropper in the swatch editor

Comment: Oh.. you want to use the Eyedropper *while* the swatch options dialog is open? No. That's not possible.  -- select the color you want, write down the numbers,, *then* edit the global color.

Comment: Yeah writing down the colors is what I do. Illustrator is such a disappointment :P

Comment: Try creating a new swatch and merging as explained [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/113733/120647)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change a color from a swatch library and actually change all the objects that have that color applied in the document?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/113732/how-do-i-change-a-color-from-a-swatch-library-and-actually-change-all-the-object)

Comment: thank you very much @Danielillo that's gold!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I don't think the color change using eyedropper is possible.

If the new color is being used in any other vector element in the document, then you can replace any color by selecting all elements and then go to Edit > Edit Colors > Recolor Artwork.

There you get a listing of all the colors used in the document (they don't have to be in the swatch list) and you can change any of them into any color you like. You just have to have the new color value available as it is not possible to choose the new color with eyedropper from the document elements.